# Mysql vs Sqlite search speed on huge SQL data

Tags: sqlite

I have 10GB MYSQL Data. It has only string and int values in 12 columns. I use it to search for string/int values. For example `"SELECT * FROM hugesql WHERE column12 LIKE 'dataexample'"`

I use Windows and i handle it with XAMPP. Phpmyadmin returns results in **a few seconds**.

I decided to use sqlite instead of mysql/phpmyadmin. Then, I exported it and i converted to sqlite db with sqlite3.exe.

I opened the sqlite file with "DB Browser for SQLite" and "SQL Studio" and queried sql code, but the search is clearly slower than phpmyadmin. a few seconds vs **1 minute**. Then, i use sqlite3 module in python, result not changed.

Any recommendations? Is it normal for SQLite?

Comment: *I use it to search for string/int values. For example* You search for complee value only? And why you use `LIKE` instead of `=`? *I exported it and i converted to sqlite db with sqlite3.exe.* Have you reproduced all indices?

Comment: @Akina I use "=" instead of "LIKE" and result not change. But i don't know about indices. I am newbie to sql. I will study indices. Thanks

Comment: sqlite and mysql are completely different products that are not expected to have any similarity in speed, and each with their own, reasonably different, use cases. To quote the [sqlite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html): *"SQLite does not compete with client/server databases. SQLite competes with fopen()."* So the main question is probably why you *"decided to use sqlite"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is not inferior to MYSQL for your use case and can handle 10GB of data easily.
However, you need to make sure your sqlite file is on a local drive and not in a network share. Otherwise a lot of data need to be moved from the file over the network and this will slow things a lot with 10GB of data.

Create appropriate indexes for your queries. For the example query you provided you need to create an index on column12.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_hugesql_12 ON hugesql(column12);
```

You only need to create each index once. It will update automatically even if you insert or update data in the table.